# Vectorizing pandas iteration

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, apply

I have a working code, which iterates `df` and returns return `other_df`. I am trying to vectorise it, as it is slow. Am trying to create a `func` to `df.apply(func)`.

The resulting dataframe is of longer length, that is why I seem to need to return an other dataframe as a result of `.apply`.

My initial `df` is a list of **apartments**, that contains a column of **lists** of **rooms** and their properties.

Each row contains something of this kind:

```
rooms                 | apartment number 

[['375', 'LET', ''],  |   12345
['335', 'LET', ''],   |
['360', 'LET', ''],   |
['295', 'double', ''],|
['360', 'LET', '']]   |
__________________________________________________
```

I need a resulting df like:

```
apartment number | room number | price | if let
   12345         | 12345-1     | 375   |  True
   12345         | 12345-2     | 335   |  True
   12345         | 12345-3     | 360   |  True
   12345         | 12345-4     | 295   |  False
   12345         | 12345-5     | 360   |  True
```

The resulting **df** should be a `df` of **rooms**. While transforming, there is some data cleaning and extraction is done, including room number assignment, based on object index in list, stored in initial df cell, which is I am not sure if possible to vectorise at all (?)

I see my options as wether to get all done at once with `.apply`, if that is possible. If it is not, than I would need to cover initial `df` into multi-index and than to pivot table.

My draft code looks like this:

```
def rooms_df(row):
    columns=['room_price',
         'room_type',
         'en_suite',
         'if_let',
         'room_number',
         'listing_id']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    for room in row['rooms']:
        number=0
        if room[0] == 'na':
            room_price = None
            room_type = None
            en_suite = None
            if_let = None
        elif room[0] == 'occupied':
            room_price = None
            room_type = None
            en_suite = None
            if_let = True
        else:
            room_price = room[0]

            if 'single' in room:
                room_type = 'single'
            elif 'double' in room:
                room_type = 'double'
            else:
                room_type = None
            if 'suite' in room:
                en_suite = True
            else:
                en_suite = False

            if 'LET' in room:
                if_let = True
            else:
                if_let = False

        listing_id = row['listing_id']

        number = number+1
        room_number = f'{listing_id}-{number}'
```

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Split your `rooms` column which is a column of list of lists into separate rows, each with a list.

   ```
   df_new = pd.DataFrame(df['rooms'].tolist()) \
   .merge(df, left_index = True, right_index = True) \
   .drop('rooms', axis=1) \
   .melt(id_vars = ['apt'], value_name = 'rooms') \
   .drop('variable', axis=1)
   ```

   OUTPUT:

   ```
   apt     rooms
   12345   ['375', 'LET', '']
   12345   ['335', 'LET', '']
   12345   ['360', 'LET', '']
   12345   ['295', 'double', '']
   12345   ['360', 'LET', '']
   ```
2. Now split each element in `rooms` into separate columns:

   ```
   df_new[['price','if_let', 'foo']] = pd.DataFrame(df_new['rooms'].values.tolist(), index=df_new.index) 
   df_new = df_new.drop(['rooms', 'foo'], axis=1)
   ```

   OUTPUT:

   ```
   apt     price   if_let  
   12345   375     LET 
   12345   335     LET 
   12345   360     LET 
   12345   295     double  
   12345   360     LET
   ```

   If you have unequal number of elements in your list, you can use `add_prefix`. This will create new columns, the number of which is equal to the maximum size of lists in the column.

   ```
   pd.DataFrame(df_new['rooms'].values.tolist(), index=df_new.index).add_prefix('foo_')
   ```

   You can rename the columns later.
3. Make new column for room number by grouping on `apt` and using `cumcount`:

   ```
   df_new['count'] = df_new.groupby('apt').cumcount()+1
   df_new['room_num'] = df_new['apt'].astype(str) + '-' + df_new['count'].astype(str)
   ```

   OUTPUT:

   ```
   apt     price   if_let  count   room_num
   12345   375     LET     1       12345-1
   12345   335     LET     2       12345-2
   12345   360     LET     3       12345-3
   12345   295     double  4       12345-4
   12345   360     LET     5       12345-5
   ```

You can now modify the columns as you like. 
For instance:

```
df_new['if_let] = np.where(df_new['if_let'] == 'LET', True, False)
```

> Try not to use `df.apply` if you have a big dataframe because it will make your operation really slow.

Comment: Thank you, it really helps! The only problem seems with the fact that lists are not consistent to each other and there is a need to fill a table based on presence of specific element in the list. I know to iterate this only.. 
Here is the possible range of types of values:

 [351, 'single', ''],
 [295, 'NOW', 'LET', ''],
 ['na'],
 ['450', 'double', 'en', 'suite', ''],

Comment: @DmitriyGrankin Is the order of elements within the list consistent (does price always come first)? I'd suggest you do some pre-processing and add empty string wherever an element is not present for a specific column. Nevertheless, I have updated step 2 to accomodate for unequal columns, but this will only work if the order is preserved.

Comment: Price indeed goes first, but other values vary. I have found solutions with df['rooms'].apply(pd.Series) to separate values to columns and using pd.where to sort values between columns, but apply is low as you have mentioned before.